# JMX in SpringBoot Application. Not able to get MBean for classes that implement an Interface

Tags: jmx, jconsole

I Have a SpringBoot application . I have used the Java config in the entire application and it is working fine.
Now I have a reqirement to configure JMX for the same.

After going through some tutorials I found that I need to give the following configuration in my spring boot to have the JMX enabled.

```
@Bean
    public MetadataNamingStrategy getNamingStrategy() {
        MetadataNamingStrategy strategy = new MetadataNamingStrategy();
        strategy.setAttributeSource(new AnnotationJmxAttributeSource());
        return strategy;
    }

    @Bean
    public MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler getMbeanInfoAssembler() {
        return new MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler(new AnnotationJmxAttributeSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public MBeanExporter getExporter() {
        MBeanExporter exporter = new MBeanExporter();
        exporter.setAutodetect(true);
        exporter.setNamingStrategy(getNamingStrategy());
        exporter.setAssembler(getMbeanInfoAssembler());
        return exporter;
    }
```

After doing this , I am able to see the classes (and their attributes, and operations) in JMX console (on HCP).
But for the classes that implement an interface ,I am not able to see them on JMX console.

Example:

I have an interface TestInterface2.

```
package com.test.example;

public interface TestInterface2 {

    public String simpleTest2();
}


The implementation of the interface goes below.

@Component("testInterfaceImpl2")
@ManagedResource(objectName = "com.test.example:type=TestInterfaceImpl2", description = "TestInterface2 Desc")
public class TestInterfaceImpl2 implements TestInterface2 {

    @Override
    public String simpleTest2() {
        return "Simple Test";
    }

}
```

I tried this. It is not working.

But the following am able see in JMX console

```
@Component
@ManagedResource(
                    objectName = "com.test.example:type=FormHandler",
                    description = "Form Handler implementation")
public class FormHandler {

    #implementation details here

}
```

Can someone suggest the best approach for doing this or why am i not able to get the interface implementations as MBean .